# Лишние отступы

Tags: css

Помогите устранить отступы, которые не понятно откуда взялись.

[image: img]

На скрине видно, что сверху и снизу формы есть отступы, скажите как их убрать и главное откуда они вообще появились, я выложу файл со стилями, посмотрите кто хорошо разбирается в css, сам я уже все перепробовал. Стили и файл с формой http://files.mail.ru/D8893E690D9541D3BC5F0EC11BDD07FD если надо то еще какие нибудь файлы выложу. Еще не могу понять почему надпись "Текст 1" не прижимается к верхнему блоку а прижимается к нижнему. Тоже гляньте пожалуйста. Вывод того самого "Текст 1"

'>Изменить
            '>Удалить

Comment: Есть сайт — http://jsfiddle.net — туда выкладывайте и ХТМЛ и стили, а не по файл-хостингам код шарьте, ужас, 1995-й год до сих пор штоле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отступ сверху можете убрать скопировав этот код:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Дневник</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="index.php" method="POST" name="foqrm">
                <textarea name="post" required placeholder="Текст" cols="40px" rows="5" ></textarea>
                <br/>
                <button class="btn-success" type="submit">Добавить</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

я убрал вставки пхп кода ваши, вернёте их обратно, с ними у меня естестно выдавало ошибку... а трабла у вас была в копировании чужого кода, ибо более непонятно как вам удалось ввести в открывающем теге form неизвестный вид less than `<`!
ещё, обратите внимание, что `</br>` - это неверно, правильно писать `<br/>`. И закрывайте link.
Что касается вашей надписи "Текст 1", если хотите чтобы вам помогли, то выкладывайте все файлы, а не обрывки кода и части файла.

PS надпись "Текст 1" скорее всего аналогично скачет вниз из-за формы, скопируйте less than `<` из, например, тега HTML и вставьте вместо всех less than `<` у ваших форм.

Comment: спасибо, с текстом разобрался, там мешал <br/> его убрал и все нормально. Я вот не понял что значит "less than <!". Объясните?

Comment: less than название значка "<".
Заменил в теге form значок < на скопированный из другого нормального тега <.
Присмотритесь, там еле заметно, но всё же видно, что < с какой-то чёрточкой чуть выше середины.